# Javascript parseInt() returning NaN on string literal containing a number

Tags: javascript, parsing

```
["57300","730","17300","17330","17340","70","220","320","380","420","340","130","50","280","360","550","43110","44340","400","620","440","20","72850"]
```

Is an array of strings being passed back into a javascript function which proceeds to do work on it to break it up into an array of strings (using the split function with "," as a delimiter).

The problem here, is I need to convert each of those after that into an integer.  Sounds easy okay.

So I proceed to do a:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item)
```

On it.  If I console log the item, I can see it being "57300", "730" etc etc.  Which is fine.  But if I try to do this:

```
var number = parseInt(item, 10);
```

And console log what number is... its NaN (should it not be 57300, 730, etc without the quotes?).  Is some hidden character messing with me causing parseInt to break?

Comment: They seem to be `["\"57300\"","\"730\"", ...]` rather than `["57300","730", ...]`

Comment: unable to recreate: http://jsfiddle.net/TSJ8J/

Comment: Please provide the *actual* code. Why do you need to split? Why is your "array" a string? Don't you decode your JSON data?

Comment: If you had to use `split` to break it up, then it wasn't an array of strings, it was just one big string. It sounds like you maybe should be using `JSON.Parse`.

Comment: It already *is* an array of strings.  Don't split it.

Comment: `console.log( JSON.stringify(data))`, what do you get?

Comment: @Esailija `data` is already "mutilated" due to splitting and whatnot, not the original data.

Comment: What is the original string you split to get the array in your question?

Comment: @phant0m ok, I just don't get "array of strings passed, that is then being splitted". doesn't make sense

Comment: It seems to be converting fine. here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/s76Fv/ Can you post some more code where exactly you getting NaN

Comment: Can we please not have what's already been said repeated any more? Thanks. --- @Esailija Neither do I, which is why I used "and whatnot", but his post hints at some processing of `data` beforehand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your initial string is like below,

```
var result = '"57300","730","17300","17330"';
```

Since you are splitting with `,` as delimiter, you will end up getting like below,

```
data = ["\"57300\"","\"730\"","\"17300\"","\"17330\""];
```

Basically a string with quotes.. And when you parse using `parseInt`

```
parseInt("\"57300\"", 10); //throws NaN
```

**Solution:**

Instead you can wrap that data with `[]` and instead of `split` use `parseJSON` function. See below,

```
var result = '"57300","730","17300","17330"';

result = '[' + result + ']';

var data = $.parseJSON(result);

$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var number = parseInt(item, 10);
    alert(number);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mYysX/

Answer (score 2):

According to your post you are splitting the string on comma which means you are leaving the quotes around the numbers.  This means you are doing the equivalent of parseInt("\"573007\"").  You would need to strip the quotes before calling parseInt.

Comment: I don't think so.. the one of the purpose of `parseInt` is to convert it to number. `Parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.` - Definition from MDN

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  He is doing the equivalent of parseInt("\"573007\"") because he has split the string on comma without removing quotes.  Result is NaN. http://jsfiddle.net/EFwcx/

Comment: @apathetic from OP _array of strings passed back into a javascript function_ - I believe he has an array already. It it not a single string.

Comment: @Vega from OP: "using the split function with "," as a delimiter"

Comment: @apathetic: If it had to be split, it isn't an array -- it's a string.  And if it's a string that looks like the stuff above, it's actually JSON and should be parsed -- which would eliminate the quotes anyway.

Comment: @apathetic mm.. You may be right.. Update the post and I would be able to remove my down vote.. especially when he said he is printing "57300" in console.. which is not supposed to happen even for a string.